# "Bowling" tag usage - any reason for dual definitions?

Tags: discussion, tags

I have altered the [bowling](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bowling) tag to refer only to the sport of bowling and not to the discipline of bowling in cricket. At time of doing so, all questions tagged [bowling](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bowling) related to the former meaning and not to the latter.

As there appeared to be no useful purpose in grouping these topics together, I went ahead and altered the definition of the tag. If anyone has any thoughts on this subject, for instance believing the two to merit joint tagging as before, please discuss here.

Comment: @waxeagle Here's your chance.

Comment: I agree with this move. The sport vs. the act in cricket are two different things. Does `bowling` for cricket need to be defined?

Comment: Perhaps [cricket-bowling] can be introduced for... well, cricket bowling. We definitely do not want a single tag to have two meanings.

Comment: @MichaelMyers I'm in agreement. However, my concern is having `cricket-this` and `cricket-that` as tags if it is not significant (reasonably scoped and useful) enough to hold water.

Comment: I would also vote for [cricket-bowling]

Comment: Mods are all in agreement. Also, note that the [original question](http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/2857/how-to-size-a-cricket-bat) with this request is not *about* cricket bowling.

Answer (score 2):

After [this](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/q/544) ongoing discussion,

If the tag is already specified as one meaning, then it should continue to specify itself as one meaning (such as [world-cup](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/world-cup) for the FIFA World Cup -- which also yield [three different sports in the first page of search results](https://www.google.com/#q=world+cup), but the other World Cups are specified as the [FIBA World Cup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIBA_Basketball_World_Cup) and the [ICC Cricket World Cup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cricket_World_Cup) respectively -- or [bowling](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bowling) for the sport of bowling -- as each are universally known as such).

For a tag like [us-open](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/us-open) in which the first page of [search results](https://www.google.com/search?q=us+open) yields three different sports, then [us-open](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/us-open) + [sport](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sport) would suffice. However, because we don't want [one tag having multiple meanings](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/388/bowling-tag-usage-any-reason-for-dual-definitions#comment882_388), the [us-open](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/us-open) tag is [ambiguous](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/a/585).

Answer (score -2):

I've been called upon to answer this as I made the suggestion for the dual usages.

Here's the thing, we have two things with the exact same name and it's easily distinguishable in context which is which.

Questions with

[cricket](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cricket) and [bowling](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bowling)

are easy distingushed from questions with just

[bowling](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bowling).

There is ultimately no need for two separate tags when the words are the same and the contexts are easily distinguishable.

Comment: Hmmm...  I would have gone with [tag:ten-pin-bowling], myself. ;-)  (See: [Ten-pin bowling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ten-pin_bowling).)