# Delete the "us-open" tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

We have a [us-open](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/us-open) tag, used on only one question.  This is really ambiguous, since there are a lot of tournaments in different sports named "US Open."  (This was pointed out to me by a new user who made a [suggested edit](https://sports.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/5640) to the tag wiki.)

We don't have a [super-bowl](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/super-bowl) tag or a [world-series](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/world-series) tag, even though we have several questions about the [Super Bowl](https://sports.stackexchange.com/search?q=super+bowl) and the [World Series](https://sports.stackexchange.com/search?q=world+series).  I don't think we need a tag for each tournament in each sport.  Can we get rid of the [us-open](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/us-open) tag?

While we are on the subject, the same user made a [suggested edit](https://sports.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/5636) to the [sweep](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sweep) tag, another (in my opinion) useless tag, used on only one question.  What do we think of that one?

Comment: I'm going to point to [Grounds of Tag Creation](http://meta.sports.stackexchange.com/questions/312/grounds-of-tag-creation) in regards to reasonably scoping tags (and the one you mention -- `sweep` -- doesn't have any clear reasonable scope that justifies its usage, unless we're going to have a subset of `trivia` in regards to such occurrences in sports). The reference may need updated however.

Comment: Also, I shared this [response](http://meta.sports.stackexchange.com/a/507) about creating a tag for the 2014 World Cup that applies here.

Comment: @jamauss Why was the following tag wiki for `sweep` approved? *"Sweep, when used in the general context above, literally refers to using a broom to sweep a floor: when used correctly, a broom will cover the entire area of a given room with dominance, encountering little to no resistance, while imposing its will (the broom: moving dust; sports teams: beating the other team) at its pleasure."*

Comment: Note: the `us-open` tag seems to have been *usable* [for this question](http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/11928/us-open-scoring-system).

Comment: A related discussion in chat: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2433/conversation/tag-for-atp-wta-year-end-championships-yec

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A year after I asked this question, we now have four questions tagged [us-open](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/us-open):  Two are about the golf tournament and two are about the tennis tournament.

The main goal of tags is to group questions about the same topic together for various purposes.  The two questions about the golf tournament and the two questions about the tennis tournament have absolutely nothing in common, except that the two tournaments just happen to have the same name.  In my opinion, this is not enough justification for a tag.

In addition, each of these questions has the text "US Open" right in the titles of the questions (as they should), making it very searchable and easy to find, if you are looking for questions about one of the US Open tournaments.

I recommend removing the tag.

Comment: I have no problem with this because of ambiguity (re: categorized because of tournaments that happen to have the same name). After review, I don't think `us-open` + `sport` or `us-open-sport` is useful. If `us-open` was specific to one event (like `world-cup` is to FIFA), then we would have carried on long ago.

Comment: Due to the three upvotes trumping other answers to this question, I have removed the `us-open` tag and updated the tag wiki.

Answer (score 3):

I think there can be us open tags but they need their respective sports included e.g. us-open-tennis, us-open-golf, etc. Not sure what not having a world series tag or super bowl tag implies.

Comment: My point was that we have questions about the Super Bowl, but no "super-bowl" tag.  (These questions are tagged "american-football" and "nfl".)  I don't think we need a tag for each tournament in each sport.

Comment: I guess I'm fine either way, with or without the tags. I just know we've had questions specific to the US Open before.

Comment: What exactly is wrong with `us-open` + `golf` or `us-open` + `tennis`? This obfuscates things. On the same token, `cricket` + `world-cup` would suffice instead of `cricket-world-cup`. If we had decided that `world-cup` is in regards to the FIFA World Cup, then having `cricket-world-cup` makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the [us-open](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/us-open) tag can be used in a similar fashion to the [world-cup](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/world-cup) tag.

@jamauss says the we've had questions specific to the US Open before. I found one and added it to the [us-open](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/us-open) tag.

Also, I have updated the tag-excerpt for the [us-open](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/us-open) to state (as the previous one was more-suited for a tag wiki, and has since been moved there):

> Questions about the US Open. This tag shall also be combined with a tag for the specific sport in question.

For any further information, a user can view the tag wiki.

This doesn't delete the tag as there are questions specific to the US Open nor does it specify itself as any one given US Open (unlike [world-cup](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/world-cup) where the tag specifies itself as the FIFA World Cup). This also doesn't obfuscate things. However, I am open to further discussion and consideration.

---

In regards to the [super-bowl](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/super-bowl) and [world-series](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/world-series) tags, I believe those tags can also work if specified in its tag wiki. That is, [super-bowl](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/super-bowl) as NFL's championship game or [world-series](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/world-series) as MLB's championship series. Or, if we want [world-series](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/world-series) to cover all such events (such as MLB's World Series and The World Series of Poker -- just an example), then we can require the tag for the specific sport in question.

---

Looking at the snapshot below, the [us-open](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/us-open) tag appears to be is useful. The questions are specific to the US Open and tagged with the specific sport in question. Does this convention work? [Related discussion](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/q/388)

[image: US Open Questions]

Comment: Thanks - I'm good with this approach. I don't think it confuses anything.